# Armature problem pose

Tags: armature

I know the correct position is when the avatar is in T pose but I have created this avatar in another pose and it why I have some problems.
I want to draw the shoes but the foot is not "flat". How can I make the change?
If you download the file the mesh and the armature have a different poses.
I appreciate also a tutorial on youtube!

Comment: You can duplicate the Armature modifier, disable the copy, change the pose and apply the Armature modifier?

Comment: You can change the rest pose with the menu entry *Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose* in *Pose* mode. To compensate for the heavy deformation of the foot and leg add a *Corrective Smooth* modifier on the body mesh after the *Armature* modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in the menu bar: Pose -> Apply -> Apply Pose as Rest Pose.
If it doesn't work you can copy the object.